# Can any weapons in Civilization III hurt all units on a square?

Tags: civilization-3

Are there any weapons (except nukes) that can deal damage to all enemy units placed on the same map square?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cruise missile and artillery units (catapult cannon, artillery and radar artillery) can do damage to multiple units and softening them up so it will be easier for your ground forces to take the city. However it's by far not as powerful as the ICBM. Still if you use artillery properly it can save you a lot of time, headache and recruits.

Comment: I have read the help for cruise missile and didn't see this explicitly specified, that's why I asked for help here. The biggest problem with nukes is getting many AIs angry, which I want to avoid :D Thank you!

Comment: Thats ok, just use artillery it's made for the same purpose as a ICBM. Or i should say a ICBM is made for the same purpose of artillery with a extra kick :D.